# Problema al declarar un string a una variable de una estructura en C

Tags: c

estoy haciendo unos programas de prueba en C para saber un poco más del lenguaje, el programa que estoy haciendo ahora es mostrar las calificaciones de unos alumnos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
struct alumno{
    char name[21];
    int edad;
    int promedio;

}alumnos[50];
int main(){
    srand (time(NULL)); 
    int cantidad, i, n;
    char names[7][10] = {"Juan", "Max", "Julia", "Pablo", "Alejandra", "Regina", "Angel"};
    char lstnames[5][10] = {"Perez", "Gonzales", "Martinez", "Rodriguez", "Contreras"};
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos: ");scanf("%i", &cantidad);
    for(i=0;i<cantidad-1;i++){
       alumnos[i].name = "%s %s",names[rand()%8], lstnames[rand()%6];
       alumnos[i].edad = rand() % 12 + 19;
       alumnos[i].promedio = rand() % 11;
       printf("\n----------\nNombre: %s\nEdad: %i\nPromedio: %i\n",alumnos[i].name, alumnos[i].edad,alumnos[i].promedio); 
        }
       return 0;
   }
```

Este es el mensaje de error que me aparece:

```
5.c: En la funci¾n 'main':
5.c:17:19: error: assignment to expression with array type
alumnos[i].name = "%s %s",names[rand()%8], lstnames[rand()%6];
                ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto:

```
"%s %s",names[rand()%8], lstnames[rand()%6];
```

puede tener sentido **como argumentos para algunas funciones**, por ejemplo `printf( )`, pero **no** de forma aislada; el lenguaje C no proporciona ese tipo de primitivas para trabajar con cadenas de caracteres.

Si lo que quieres es generar una cadena de texto a partir de una cadena de formato y ciertos argumentos, guardando el contenido en una posición concreta de memoria, las funciones a utilizar son `sprintf( )` o `snprintf( )`:

> The functions in the printf() family produce output according to a format
>   ...
>   `sprintf( )` and `snprintf( )` write to the character string str.

De forma general, es preferible usar `snprintf( )`, puesto que limita el total de caracteres *impresos* a un máximo. Así evitamos problemas de *pasarnos* de las zonas de memoria asignadas:

```
for( i = 0; i < cantidad - 1; i++ ) {
  snprintf( &( alumnos[i].name ), sizeof( alumnos[i].name ), "%s %s",names[rand( ) % 8], lstnames[rand( ) % 6] );
  alumnos[i].edad = rand( ) % 12 + 19;
  alumnos[i].promedio = rand( ) % 11;
  printf("\n----------\nNombre: %s\nEdad: %i\nPromedio: %i\n",alumnos[i].name, alumnos[i].edad,alumnos[i].promedio); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Empieza por quitar el cantidad-1 y dejar cantidad, "asi no se te va la PINZA",
char name[21]
alumnos[i].name[?¿] = si name es un *[]? 
enga que con eso ***puedes

;)

---

```
   char aleatorio[21];
   strcpy(aleatorio,names[rand()%7]);
   strcat(aleatorio, " ");
   strcat(aleatorio,lstnames[rand()%5]);

   strcpy(alumnos[i].name,  aleatorio);
```

---